# How to find the matched names in different datasets' columns?

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets with columns having the same names.

a:

```
A B C
1 2 3
5 6 7
```

b:

```
B E A
2 3 4
9 1 2
```

How can I find the column indices with the matched names?

I have tried converting them from wide to long format by using `gather()` respectively and matching both datasets with `match(a,b)`. It didn't work.

Comment: What would be the result of your example data?

Comment: You need to match the column names, not the data frames. Try `match(colnames(a), colnames(b))` which returns `[1]  3  1 NA`. Column a$A is the same as column b[, 3], column a$B is the same as column b[, 1], and column a$C is not matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Find common column names in the two dataframes
intersect(names(a), names(b))
#[1] "A" "B"

#Find the column number in a which is present in b
which(names(a) %in% names(b))
#[1] 1 2

#find the column number in b which is present in a
which(names(b) %in% names(a))
#[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use grep for this

```
grep(pattern = paste(names(a), collapse = "|") , x = names(b))
```